# How to stop the line in cventry being in italics

Tags: itemize, cv

I am using the template for a CV on Overleaf and one of the sections for my academic records uses \cventry, which I like as it makes it look good. https://www.overleaf.com/4565321zzdfbr#/13750580/

The Latex code looks like this:

```
\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{}{Masters in Theoretical Physics}{University of sussex}{2014 - 
current}{}{1st year result - 80 per cent (first class classification)
{\textit{}}{}}   

\item{\cventry{}{A Levels: Mathematics (A), Physics (A), Chemistry (A)}{The 
Archbishop's School, Canterbury}{2007 - 2014}{}{AS Levels: History (A), 
Further Mathematics (B)}{\textit{}}{}}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\item{\cventry{}{Three 6th Form Prizes: Mathematics best result; Physics best 
result; Chemistry best result}{Academic Awards}{}{}{}{\textit{}}{}}

\end{itemize}
```

I have attached a screen shot of how this appears.[image: How it appears]

How can I stop the second line of each part being in italics?

Comment: Welcome, there are many cv templates on Overleaf. Can you give us a more specific pointer, i.e. a link?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/4565321zzdfbr#/13750580/

Comment: Well, that template starts with `\small{...}`, which is a clear sign the author knows very little LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to patch `\cventry` so that it doesn't issue `\itshape` when typesetting its second argument.

You surely *don't* want the bullets to appear in the middle of the entry, do you? Don't use `itemize`. However, if you do, remove the braces around the item text:

```
\item Whatever
```

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{textcomp,xpatch}

%%% Patch \cventry so the second argument is not printed in italics
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\itshape#3}{#3}{}{}


% personal data
\name{First}{Last}
\address{12345 One Street, Sometown}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{(999)-555-5555}
\email{first.last@mail.xyz}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cventry{}
  {Masters in Theoretical Physics}
  {University of Sussex}
  {2014 -- current}
  {}
  {1st year result - 80 per cent (first class classification)}
  {}{}

\end{document}
```

The `textcomp` package avoids a spurious warning; `xpatch` is needed for `\xpatchcmd`. Note also how I think it's best to input the `\cventry` data.

[image]

Comment: Haha, yes I wanted also to get rid of those awful bullet points in the middle of the paragraph, strange style! Thanks a lot, really helpful.