# Class moderncv: own \cventry leads to problem with linebreak using tabularx

Tags: tabularx, moderncv

I wanted to define my own cv-entry called `\mycventry` based on the solution of the accepted answer in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402806/moderncv-get-rid-of-italic-in-cventry).

This led to this code:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page


\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\bfseries#3 \newline}%
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\newline {#4}}%sth to describe
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{\hspace{1cm} #5}%description
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
            #4 & #5 
        \end{tabularx}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\newline #6}%
        \strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}





% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{10cm}            % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[xing]{john\_doe}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[skype]{jdoe}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
%\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

%\moderncvstyle{fancy}
\section{Education}
\mycventry{year--year}{Degree}{sth-todescribe:}{Description starts here. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. But it should stop before the end of the page.}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty



\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

[image]

My Question are:

1. How can I increase the distance between `sth-to-describe:` and the
   description?
2. The exact width of the second column (explanation) is not known. If
   `sth-to-describe` changes, the width of the second column also
   changes. How can automatic linebreak be implemented without knowing
   the exact width of the column, so that the description is breaked
   exactly at the end to the line and not at the end of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `\textwidth` to `\linewidth`, because the layout of `moderncv` uses a two column layout: the first column is for the dates and the rules in section title, the second column with its own `\linewidth` (!) for descriptions ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\bfseries#3 \newline}%
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\newline {#4}}%sth to describe
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{\hspace{1cm} #5}%description
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X} % <===========================
            #4 & #5 
        \end{tabularx}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\newline #6}%
        \strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi%
  }%
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,
  showframe, % <==================== to visualize typing area and margins
]{geometry}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{10cm}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[xing]{john\_doe}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[skype]{jdoe}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

%\moderncvstyle{fancy}
\section{Education}
\mycventry%
  {year--year-2}%
  {Degree-3}%
  {sth-todescribe:-4}%
  {Description starts here. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. This text needs automatic linebreak due to it's length. But it should stop before the end of the page.-5}%
  {\textit{Grade}-6}%
  {Description-7}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty



\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

To get a better looking add some space between the `l` and the `X` column, for example with:

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l p{1em} X} % <====================
        #4 & & #5 % <===============================================
    \end{tabularx}
```

with the result:

[image]